# How To Use Publication Without Precompiled Partitions

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

I am using SQL 2012 with merge replication. Our setup is quite complicated and thus it seems running the publication with precompiled partitions is not going to work.

The merge agent is slow to do the first sync because of calling the sp_mssetupbelongs stored procedure.

I am wondering if it is viable to run the publication without precompiled partitions?

The first sync is faster without precompiled partitions, but subsequent syncs are a bit slower than before. Just a few changes will result in a sync of about 5 minutes.

I also tried an option called 'Optimize Partitions' and would like to know what this does? Deleting a record at the publication end did not propagate to the subscribers. The subsequent syncs were faster though. Why do deletes not propagate, and is there a workaround for this?